# Inject custom React component

Tags: reactjs

On a React app, a client needs to customize some pages for some specific needs.
Is it possible to inject some custom JS / React component and "override" the behavior of an other component?

I don't want to keep the custom component on the bundle all the time and do some control because other clients may customize other features as well ...

Basically, I'm trying to inject a custom JS with a custom component inside and use it.

Anyone had to do samething like this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your customer wants to write some of the code themselves and have it work with the code you are writing for them. Is that right? This really sounds like an XY problem. If I were a consultant in this situation, I would discuss the business needs of the client and build a feature/system that meets those needs.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we had kind of the same problem and it can get very messy. You can use `window.eval()` if you import an external js code to make it run in your project but I would not recommend it at all as it gave us a lot of headaches...

That would be for JS code which are instructions and not components.

If your client has their own components maybe you can suggest them to create a node library so you can import their comps.

Comment: Yes, they can create and publish a library, but, the library will still be complied on the main bundle...